# Can 「に」, 「は」 and 「を」 be used as 終助詞 (particles at the end of the sentence)?

Tags: grammar, particles, sentence-final-particles

I would like to understand more about the practical use of the *shūjoshi*. 
な、かしら、かな、の、ぜ、わ、こと were some I found. But I already saw に、は、を being used in the same way. Are they also *shūjoshi*?

Comment: I assume that you are referencing expressions where the final part of the sentence (after the particle) is simply omitted due to expectation on the part of the speaker that the context is already understood by the listener. It would help if you provided specific examples of which sentences you are referring to.